# Generating publicPath url on Runtime - Webpack 4 + ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, chunks

What I would like to achieve is a dynamic publicPath url using react + webpack to smoothen a deployment process. Currently, I have 3 endpoints (test,prod,build) where the application loads chunks from based on the build script. I'd like to be able to swap these endpoints dynamically without having to re-build the application. Is this possible in any way?

Thank you in advance :)

current webpack config for reference:

```
const getOriginalConfig = require('@nrwl/react/plugins/webpack')
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin

module.exports = (config, env) => {
  const rootWebpackConfig = getOriginalConfig(config)

  const output = rootWebpackConfig.output
  const url =
    process.env.NX_NODE_ENV === 'development'
      ? '{dev-endpoint}'
      : process.env.NX_NODE_ENV === 'test'
      ? '{test-endpoint}'
      : process.env.NX_NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? '{prod-endpoint}'
      : '/'

  const updatedConfig = {
    ...rootWebpackConfig,
    output: {
      ...output,
      publicPath: url
    },
    plugins: [...rootWebpackConfig.plugins, new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({ analyzerMode: 'disabled' })]
  }

  return updatedConfig
}
```